# Modify the computation graph of a tf.function [Tensorflow 2]

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have an external library that I use to build a Tensorflow model and wrap it inside a `tf.function`. This model have some `Variables` that I want to feed in, but some of these variables can be precomputed for a faster inference.

Suppose to have a graph like this one:
[image: simple computation graph]

Where `A` and `B` are model parameters and `x` is the model input used for inference.

Here, once the model is trained and ready for inference, `C` can be precomputed since I already know `A` and `B`. For this reason, I want to modify the computation graph to look like this:

[image: Optimized computation graph]

Where I can still feed the model parameters `C` (e.g. I could freeze the graph and turn `C` to constant, but I need to feed `C` externally).

What I tried to do is something like this:

```py
graph_def = ... # get graph def from saved model or tf.function's Concrete function 

with tf.Graph().as_default() as modified_graph:
    C = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64, 64]), name = 'PrecomputedC')

    tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map={'<name of node C>' : C})
```

How can I turn the modified graph back into a `tf.function` or `saved_model` and be able to feed the variable `PrecomputedC`?

Thanks!

Comment: If `A` and `B` are "frozen" (constant) values, then TensorFlow should do this optimization by itself when the graph is loaded, it's what is called "constant folding" and it is covered by Grappler, see [TensorFlow graph optimization with Grappler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_optimization).

Comment: Yes indeed, I tried to freeze the graph and it works just fine. 
However for my purposes, I need to have a graph where I can change the variables from outside so they can't be constants..